# Using Pandas, why is the column/series header not showing at the top of an output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, series

In:

```
def answer_three():
    Top15 = answer_one()
    
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826751/average-of-dataframe-columns
    
    Top15['avgGDP'] = Top15[['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']].mean(axis=1)
    Top15 = Top15.sort_values('avgGDP', ascending=False)
    
    return Top15['avgGDP']

answer_three()
```

Out:

```
Country      
UU           15368
CF            6348
J             5542
G             3493
F             2681
UT            2487
B             2189
IA            2120
IB            1769
CG            1660
R             1565
S             1418
A             1164
S             1106
T             7704
Name: avgGDP, dtype: float64
```

Observation:

The header/series name shows at the bottom along with the datatype.  I have researched and can't find the answer, only adding/renaming headers, extracting only headers, etc.  That is not my problem, I simply want the output to look when I call a dataframe normally, but only this select/singular field in this case, i.e. i want:

```
Country      avgGDP
UU           15368
CF            6348
J             5542
G             3493
F             2681
UT            2487
B             2189
IA            2120
IB            1769
CG            1660
R             1565
S             1418
A             1164
S             1106
T             7704
```

The only thing I see different between output a full frame and this is that I am requesting a single specific column.  I am assuming I have to add something to my return statement, so it output like I called a full dataframe.

I appreciate your time and assistance in advance!

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: `Top15['avgGDP']` returns a `Series`, which is 1d.  Double check the docs, but a `Series` might not have a `columns` attribute.  `Top15[['avgGDP']]` would give you a 1 column DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Series name is always shown under the Series. A DataFrame column name is shown above the column. You can convert the Series into a one-column DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(Top15['avgGDP'])
```

It will be displayed as you expect.

Comment: That did the trick.  I understand.  I was only creating a view, but for what I want I need to create a new DataFrame.  Makes sense now.  Thanks DYZ!!!